# Unable to Launch the Administrator tool of Mirth

Tags: hl7, mirth

I have Mirth Connect Version 2.2.3.6825 installed on RHL I want to access my Mirth  my Local Machine which have Java 1.8(Java 1.7 it Work fine),  I am not able to launch the Administrator tool of Mirth. When I clicked on the administrator button, It opened the window saying starting application after giving User name and Password it give  error 'There was an error connecting to the server at the specified address. Please verify that the server is up and running'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/wiki/display/mirth/System+Requirements

Java 8 should work with version 2.2.3, but you must be using the Oracle JRE. OpenJDK only recently became supported with version 3.7.

You may also want to try using the new Administrator Launcher available on the mirth downloads page. It comes bundled with a Java 8 JVM so that you don't need to install one separately. It works with all versions of mirth from 2.x and up. See announcement here: https://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/showthread.php?t=218662